# Django Rest API updating-instance problem

Tags: json, django, rest

I'm new on working with Django Rest API, so I have a problem with updating. When I save the instance, I just call save method of serializer instance. But when I update the serializer instance by its id, I must give an instance to update the method. Right now I have another question. Due to Django rest API [docs](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L61)

```
class UpdateModelMixin:
"""
Update a model instance.
"""
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()

def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Does it always get an instance from DB (like this query `SELECT *FROM Table1 WHERE id=1`) when it updates instance? And it copies all fields one by one due to that [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). If it works so, does it execute two queries when an instance is been updated? And another problem is that if models have nested fields.

Please, give me advice there another option to solve this problem. I find one way to solve this problem is to use ordinary SQL queries, but I don't like do it.

Comment: What would you like to do exactly, partially updated few fields of an instance?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to get an instance from DB, getting an instance from is extra work, I have enough fields to update.